# Does Array.pop() mess array's length?

Tags: javascript

I am trying the following code in ideone:

```
var a = [];
a[0] = 0;
a[5] = 5;
a[6] = undefined;
print("contents before popping:");
for(var e in a) print("\ta[", e, "] =", a[e]);
print("a.length =", a.length);
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    print("\ta.hasOwnProperty(", i, ") =", a.hasOwnProperty(i));

print("popping -->", a.pop());
print("popping -->", a.pop());
print("contents after popping:");
for(var e in a) print("\ta[", e, "] =", a[e]);
print("a.length =", a.length);
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    print("\ta.hasOwnProperty(", i, ") =", a.hasOwnProperty(i));
```

The output goes as follows:

```
contents before popping:
    a[ 0 ] = 0
    a[ 5 ] = 5
    a[ 6 ] = undefined
a.length = 7
    a.hasOwnProperty( 0 ) = true
    a.hasOwnProperty( 1 ) = false
    a.hasOwnProperty( 2 ) = false
    a.hasOwnProperty( 3 ) = false
    a.hasOwnProperty( 4 ) = false
    a.hasOwnProperty( 5 ) = true
    a.hasOwnProperty( 6 ) = true
popping --> undefined
popping --> 5
contents after popping:
    a[ 0 ] = 0
a.length = 5
    a.hasOwnProperty( 0 ) = true
    a.hasOwnProperty( 1 ) = false
    a.hasOwnProperty( 2 ) = false
    a.hasOwnProperty( 3 ) = false
    a.hasOwnProperty( 4 ) = false
```

In my JavaScript book (well, Crockford's) I read that array's length is calculated as the biggest numerical value of all properties. So, why does it say the length is 5 when the biggest numerical property it has is 0? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A nice thing about Javascript is that its semantics is formally and as unambiguously as possible defined in the standard. Specifically, [section 15.4](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4) states that:

> The value of the length property is numerically greater than the name of every property whose name is an array index; whenever a property of an Array object is created or changed, other properties are adjusted as necessary to maintain this invariant.

In other words, everytime you change an array, its `length` is adjusted, however, it's only guaranteed to be greater than `max(indexes)`, and not necessarily equal to `max(indexes)+1`. For example, the [pop method](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.6) always removes the `length-1`'th element and decrements `length` by one, no matter how many elements an array actually contains.

Also do note that most array methods are generic and don't "know" anything about arrays specifically. They can manipulate arbitrary objects, and if such an object happens to have a property named `length`, it will be adjusted according to the above rule. Consider:

```
foo = {
    length: 100,
    99: 'hi'
}

alert([].pop.apply(foo)) // hi
alert(foo.length)        // 99

alert([].pop.apply(foo)) // undefined
alert(foo.length)        // 98
```

That is, in the context of your question it's irrelevant how exactly arrays are represented - `pop` and friends don't use this information.

Comment: I've been passing this fiddle around to demonstrate when Array.length is unreliable, in addition to your example. http://jsfiddle.net/6WrkT/1/

Answer (score 1):

The "*problem*" is the *assignment* of `5`.

The second you do that, the *Javascript Array* gets filled up with slots which get initialized with the `undefined` value.

So calling

```
a[5] = 5;
```

causes

```
[0, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 5]
```

Then you create also `a[6]` and initialize it with `undefined` and we get

```
[0, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 5, undefined]
```

`.length` of `7`.

Now we call a *double* `.pop()` (love the word doublepop) and we get

```
[0, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

`.length` of **5**

---

Actually, as pointed out in the comments, this still seems to be very odd behavior. When initializing any index, the slots before are not really assigned by anything. It creates a *sparse array*. But then again, if we remove the last two entries, there is only one value left (`0`) followed by `undefined` values (which *somehow* became *real* values, probably because we assigned a `6` manually).

I guess we need an implementation Guru :)

Comment: The array does not get filled since `hasOwnProperty` returns `false`

Comment: I am not sure that the intermediate values are initialized to `undefined`, I rather think `a` is a sparse array.

Comment: @lmsteffan you're actually right, I'm confused by myself now. It seems like my description fits, but actually, there should be no slots left.

Comment: I could imagine the explanation being correct nevertheless, but the browser differentiating between an "automatically filled" undefined and an undefined that was explicitly set.

Comment: Differentiating in the sense of whether it counts as a "hasOwnProperty" that is. But it would be something that sounds like a really big quirk, maybe even a bug. Does this behave the same in all browsers?

Comment: The last `undefined` is different from the auto initialized `undefined`, [note the difference in colors](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tKuIz.png).

Comment: @Antony yes, we know. But we `pop()` those two last values. Like I mentioned in my update, somehow the implementation creates "real" `undefined` values on the slots before.

Comment: There are no `undefined` values in the unused slots, that's the result from reading a slot that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

> "array's length is calculated as the biggest numerical value of all
>   properties"

That's not accurate for all uses of an array. It works that way if you assign a value to an index in the array, but not if you set the `length` specifically or use methods like `pop`.

Example:

```
var a = [];
a.length = 5;

console.log("length =", a.length);

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
  console.log("a.hasOwnProperty(", i, ") =", a.hasOwnProperty(i));
```

Output:

```
length = 5
a.hasOwnProperty(0) = false
a.hasOwnProperty(1) = false
a.hasOwnProperty(2) = false
a.hasOwnProperty(3) = false
a.hasOwnProperty(4) = false
```

Now you have an array without any items in it, but the length is 5.

Comment: but the question remains, why and where become the slots `1...4` *real* slots with the `undefined` value ? Actually as @lamsteffan pointed out correctly, we're just dealing with a sparse array.

Comment: @jAndy I guess Guffa has it right. `Array.splice` and direct assignment of `length` show the same behavior and the reason really seems to be that the `length` gets assigned at some point.

Comment: @jAndy: The unused slots doesn't have any values, but if you try to read from a slot that doesn't exist, you get `undefined` back. For example `console.log([][42]);` shows `undefined`.

Comment: @Guffa I know that. But I'm confused because after we `pop` on the last two values, the length is still `5`. When exactly gets the `.length` branded ? Mhh I guess with the assignment and then it never gets reset again... ok that makes sense :p

Comment: @jAndy: The `pop` method doesn't care about empty slots. It gets the last item according to the `length` property and reduces the `length` by one. You can even apply the `pop` method on any object that has a `length` property, it doesn't even have to be an array: http://jsfiddle.net/4kucg/

Comment: @Guffa hell, thats bluff'ish.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is really related to the fact that you are not using sequential indexes rather than to the fact that you are using the pop function. You'll notice that on the first length print the length of the array is 7, though you only have 3 items in the array. This is related to the fact that length is returning the maximal index/property (+1), since the rest of the values are set as undefined values.

Do you really have to go with non-sequential indexes? If so, you might want to try and use:

```
var counter = 0;
for (var i in a) {
    counter++;
  print("Property: "+i);
}
print("Total items: "+counter);
```

But that's far from being optimal, performance wise.

Comment: Hello, I am not having any problems with the code. This is pure artificial construct as I am merely trying to understand the language. I am looking for the explanation as to why it works this way, not how to fix it

Comment: Got you. Then I would have to agree with the answer above, though I am not sure that the same behavior is the same in all browsers.